# Checkout, guest is not showing up

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, onepage-checkout

I've found a strange behavior, something related with the cache, I guess.

When I'm in the checkout just give me the options:

> - register
> - login

And I'm pretty sure that "Checkout as guest" is enabled.

And when I navigate in private mode I can see the checkout as guest.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Checking the file: ../template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml 
and there is a condition

```
<?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
```

The really weird thing is that when I'm in private mode (still with that xD) or in a browser with clear cache or in a browser that I've never used that condition is true, but other way is false.

Comment: "something related with the cache" -> which cache do you mean? do you have a specific block cache module running? out of the box this block/html isnt cached.

Comment: I thought that but really don't know what can be. 
I'm not sure what do you mean with "block cache module running", but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading about "Persistent car"

> I think you don't understand the cocept of "persistent shopping cart" in Magento.
>   This has nothing to to with allowing guest checkout or not.
>   The only thing that it does, is to set a cookie that will allow the customer in his next visit to the website [...]
>   [persistent shopping cart disadvantages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18435/persistent-shopping-cart-disadvantages)

So I suppose that it was the cookie that cause that behavior. 
I set to No "Persistent Shopping Cart", and solved that issue with the guest but is kinda frustrating because I've had to disable the "Remember me", I guess that I've to choose between one and another.

> "During the time a persistent shopping cart is use, both registered
>   customers and guest shoppers are required to either log in to an
>   existing account, or create a new account before going through the
>   checkout process"
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-persistent-shopping-cart

So there's the answer.
Thanks to everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The checkout is largely uncached, so you shouldn't have a cache problem with a stock installation. It sounds like you've got a custom theme or made modifications that are causing your issue.

Start by checking the block instance class for the first step of the accordion, and verify that the respective cache methods are returning the appropriate values.

Eg.

```
getCacheLifetime() { return null; }
```

Will ensure the block isn't cached.

You should disable each cache type in the admin, one by one and test between each. You'll identify the cause then.

It worryingly sounds like you have configured Varnish (and very badly at that), as a stock install will never cache the checkout.

Comment: Well I thought that because when I check in private mode everything works fine.
And yes I have all the cache disabled.
But I'm gonna check with the console what's going on in the first step of the accordion.

Comment: Are you using Varnish?

Comment: No, just the magento cache, anything extra related to cache