# Magento Persistence and Guest Checkout strange behavior

Tags: checkout, cart, persistent

today we had an interesting situation. We have 3 stores, all with guest checkout enabled. Today (only) 1 store suddenly reported "no guest checkout available" messages in the last step of checkout.

After some digging in Google there appears to be a relation between this error and the `Persistent Shopping Cart`. If we disable `Persistent Shopping Cart` the Guest Checkout works again.

Question:
we enjoy having persistence turned on, but how can we prevent this situation where  `no guest checkout available` breaks our conversion?

Is there a way to fix this and still have `Persistent Shopping Cart` turned on?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: As i can't comment due to low reputation count i have to write this as an answer: Did you disable the "Persistent Shopping cart" only? Or did you also disable "Enable Persistence"? I have this strange behaviour in a Magento 1.7.0.2 too. From time to time, out of sudden the last step produces an error with No guest checkout available. I'm thinking about a session/persistence cookie timing/timeout problem, but i never can really force the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our solution was to disable persistent shopping cart

Somehow when a customer had an old cookie and they tried to checkout as customer - even although all settings pointed to guest checkout being enabled - this was not possible.

Comment: You may also want to check [this solution](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63833/142).